# How to combine multiple key values in JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this sample JSON object

```
var sample = [{
    "label": "one",
    "value": 1
}, {
    "label": "two",
    "value": 2
}, {
    "label": "three",
    "value": 3
}, {
    "label": "four",
    "value": 4
}, {
    "label": "five",
    "value": 5
}];
```

I want to change it some thing like this

```
var sample = [{
    "label": "one",
    "value": 1,
    "newKeyValue": "one|1"
}, {
    "label": "two",
    "value": 2,
    "newKeyValue": "two|2"
}, {
    "label": "three",
    "value": 3,
    "newKeyValue": "three|3"
},
...
];
```

It should combine both key values and return new key value combining both.

JSON is coming dynamically key label and value are not static it can be anything. For example `[{"name":"srinivas","lastname":"pai"}]`

Comment: try by `$.extend(targetSample,Sample)`;

Comment: @Tushar No not tried.

Comment: I tried using for loop only single value I can add @Tushar

Comment: The way you posted your question seems a little confusing. I suggest to add, that the actual keys are not static but can differ from time to time, as you already did in some comments.

Comment: and how do you keep the order of the keys?

Answer (score 4):

You can use map like this :

**EDIT**

For handling generic keys you can use 
`Object.keys(d)[0]` for first key
`Object.keys(d)[1]` for second key

```js
var sample = [

     {
      "label":"one",
      "value":1
     },

     {
      "label":"two",
      "value":2
     },
     {
      "label":"three",
      "value":3
     },
     { 
      "label":"four",
      "value":4
     },
     { 
      "label":"five",
      "value":5
      }

     ];
    var data = sample.map(function(d){
     return {label: Object.keys(d)[0], value: Object.keys(d)[1], newKeyValue:  Object.keys(d)[0] +"|" + Object.keys(d)[1]}
    }) 
    console.log(data)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for quick response. json is coming dynamically key label and value are not static it can be anything. for example [{"name":"srinivas","lastname":"pai"}]

Comment: Check edit section you can do it generically like this too

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

In ES6, you can use [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
sample = sample.map(obj => {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    obj.newKeyValue = keys.map(key => obj[key]).join('|');
    return obj;
});
```

```js
var sample = [{
    "label": "one",
    "value": 1
}, {
    "name": "two",
    "age": 2
}, {
    "five": "three",
    "six": 3
}, {
    "company": "four",
    "organization": 4
}, {
    "label": "five",
    "value": 5
}];

sample = sample.map(function (x) {
    var keys = Object.keys(x);
    x.newKeyValue = keys.map(key => x[key]).join('|');
    return x;
});
console.log(sample);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sample, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

In ES5, you can use the same code with anonymous functions

```
sample = sample.map(function (obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    obj.newKeyValue = keys.map(function (key) {
        return obj[key]
    }).join('|');
    return obj;
});
```

**Limitations due to dynamic keys:**

1. The order of the keys in object cannot be maintained
2. This will join all the available keys in the object (*in case if you just want to join fewer*)

Comment: thank you @tushar  json is coming dynamically key label and value are not static it can be anything. for example [{"name":"srinivas","lastname":"pai"}]

Comment: @SrinivasPai Can you add more details regarding this in the questino

Comment: @SrinivasPai I've updated the answer to make the keys dynamic. Please check again. Also note that, if the object contain multiple keys, it'll join them all with `|` as separator.

Comment: **One-liner** `sample = sample.map(obj => Object.assign(obj, {
    newKeyValue: Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]).join('|')
}));`

Answer (score 2):

```js
var sample = [

         {
          "label":"one",
          "value":1
         },

         {
          "label":"two",
          "value":2,
          "optionalValue":2
         },
         {
          "label":"three",
          "value":3,
          "remarks":"free text"
         },
         { 
          "label":"four",
          "value":4
         },
         { 
          "label":"five",
          "value":5
          }

         ];

    for (var key in sample) {
      var newValue = [];
      for (var piece in sample[key]){
        newValue.push(sample[key][piece])
      }
      sample[key]["newKeyValue"] = newValue.join('|');
    }

    $('pre').html(JSON.stringify(sample,null,4));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for in situ changes.

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

Edit: with dynamic keys, stored in an array, because of the order.

```js
var sample = [{ "label": "one", "value": 1 }, { "label": "two", "value": 2 }, { "label": "three", "value": 3 }, { "label": "four", "value": 4 }, { "label": "five", "value": 5 }];

sample.forEach(function (a) {
    a.newKeyValue = ['label', 'value'].map(function (k) { return a[k]; }).join('|');
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sample, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If more element are their then use [$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

```js
var sample = [

         {
          "label":"one",
          "value":1
         },

         {
          "label":"two",
          "value":2
         },
         {
          "label":"three",
          "value":3
         },
         { 
          "label":"four",
          "value":4
         },
         { 
          "label":"five",
          "value":5
          }

         ];
        $(sample).each(function(i,item){
            var keyes = Object.keys(item);
            sample[i] =  $.extend(item,{newKeyValue: item[keyes[0]] +"|" +item[keyes[1]]});
        });
       
        console.log(sample)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`$.extend` also helpful when you are having more objects already and you want to merge both 
**eg**.

```
  var base  = {
          "label":"one",
          "value":1
         }
```

and you want to add more objects

```
 var extra  =  {
          "new1":"value1",
          "new2":"value2",
          "new3":"value3",
          "new4":"value4",
       }
```

then it will be done by

```
$.extend(base,extra);
```

**Output**:

```
        {
              "label":"one",
              "value":1,
              "new1":"value1",
              "new2":"value2",
              "new3":"value3",
              "new4":"value4",
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sample = [{"name":"srinivas","lastname":"pai"}];    

sample.map(function(item) {
  item.newKeyValue = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item).map(function(d) {return item[d];}).join("|");
})

    console.log(sample);
```

Comment: json is coming dynamically key label and value are not static it can be anything. for example [{"name":"srinivas","lastname":"pai"}]